# in aspectj, can we define handler together with certain annotation?

Tags: annotations, handler, aspectj

I want to only do exception handle for methods that annotate with self-defined annotation,

like below

```java
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.common.CollectException) && execution(* *(..))")
public void annotationPointCutDefinition() { }

@Before("annotationPointCutDefinition() && handler(*) && args(e)")
public void logCaughtException(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Throwable e) {
    //System.out.println(e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    System.out.println("count = " +
        ", " +
        thisJoinPoint + " -> " +
        e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

but for a method marked with my self-defined annotation, it did not get weaved with logCaughtException function

```java
@CollectException
public void divideByZeroWithCatch(){
    try{
        int a = 5/0;
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Can not divide by zero");
    }
}
```

I am wrong with above usage? if so would someone pls give some advice here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this really about AspectJ or rather about proxy-based Spring AOP? In the latter case, it could be as simple as your target class not being a Spring-managed bean/component or you using a configuration using JDK proxies only, but the target class not implementing any interfaces. In order to say for sure, I need more details, not just snippets. Ideally, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here or on GitHub. Make your problem reproducible, and you will get help relatively quickly.

Comment: thank you! I have been seeing several stackoverflow posts answered by you for aspectj. And I followed one of you example to try the combination usage of handler of catch and annotation. here is the github link https://github.com/LizzyMiao/AspectJRelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. There are several problems in your aspect code:

In your GitHub repository you use `@within(x.y.CollectException)`. That would intercept joinpoints in annotated classes, but your example class has an annotated method, the class itself is not annotated. Therefore, that pointcut would never match.

In your sample code here, you had the right idea to use `@annotation(x.y.CollectException)` in order to intercept annotated methods. You even added `&& execution(* (..))` so as to limit matching to `execution` pointcuts and exclude `call` ones. Otherwise the pointcut would fire twice per method in AspectJ (not in Spring AOP where there are not `call` joinpoints). So far, so good.

**But** just like `call` and `execution` are not the same and therefore mutually exclusive, so are `execution` and `handler`. A `handler` joinpoint is usually somewhere *inside* (the **control flow** of) a method execution, but it *is not* the method execution. This is also your clue to the solution. You actually want to limit matching to exception handlers in the control flow of an annotated method:

```java
@Pointcut("@annotation(de.scrum_master.common.CollectException) && execution(* *(..))")
public void annotationPointCutDefinition() { }

@Before("cflow(annotationPointCutDefinition()) && handler(*) && args(e)")
public void logCaughtException(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Throwable e) {
  System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

In your GitHub example, you will see the following line in the console log:

```
handler(catch(ArithmeticException)) -> java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

Comment: I'm new to AspectJ, didn't know cflow can do the effect, thank you for the patience and kindness!